# Why are values being retrieved after post request going out of div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

[image]

The last card you see is information being retrieved after a post request to add a review from a form into the json server db, and its going outside the div.

Where as the reviews being entered manually inside the json db are being retrieved and displayed just perfectly as you can see.

Could anyone please help with this? I am attaching my code below.

---

RenderList.js is the code for displaying the cards you see below.

---

```
import React,{Fragment} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {getList, getReviews, calculateAverage} from '../../actions';
import { Button, Icon, Image, Item, Label, Rating, Modal, Header, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import '../../styles.css';


class RenderList extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){

  }


  renderList() {
    const listReview = this.props.list;
    return (listReview || []).map(l => {
      if(this.props.starVal == undefined){

        return (
          <div class="ui card">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">{l.title}</div>
              <div style={{float:"right"}}>
                <Rating size="large" icon="star" disabled defaultRating={l.rating} maxRating={5}> </Rating>
              </div>
              <div style={{marginTop:"12px"}} class="meta"> by {l.name}</div>
              <div style={{marginTop:"12px"}} class="description">{l.review}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
       if(l.rating == this.props.starVal) {
        return (
          <div class="ui card">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">{l.title}</div>
              <div style={{float:"right"}}>
                <Rating size="large" icon="star" disabled defaultRating={l.rating} maxRating={5}> </Rating>
              </div>
              <div style={{marginTop:"12px"}} class="meta"> by {l.name}</div>
              <div style={{marginTop:"12px"}} class="description">{l.review}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
              );
      }
            });
            }

            render() {
              return (

                <div>
                  <div class="ui cards" style={{  overflow: "auto", maxHeight: "50vh", marginTop:"0px"}} >{this.renderList()}</div>
                </div>
              );
            }
            }

        const mapStateToProps = state => {
          return {
            list: Object.values(state.list),
            starVal: state.list.starValue

          };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getReviews, calculateAverage })(RenderList);
```

---

db.json is the json db from which the value is being retrieved.

---

```
{
  "reviews": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test User",
      "title": "Perfect",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test User",
      "title": "Decent Product",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Test User",
      "title": "Easy Installation",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Test User",
      "title": "Not bad",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Test Userkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnk",
      "title": "Does the job",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Test User",
      "title": "Hey",
      "review": "this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product, this is a great product",
      "rating": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "jknjknjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnknjknkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnkjnk",
      "title": "jnjnkjnkjnkjkn",
      "review": " n n n jn jhjhbhjbjnkjnjuhiubihbibbkjbnjknkjbjhbjkbkjbkjbkbkhbjbjkbkjbjkbkjbjbkjbjkbjkbjbjkbkjbjbkjbkjbjbkjb",
      "rating": 2
    }
  ],
  "stars": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "one": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "two": 2000
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "three": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "four": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "five": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't have a space between to have a line break.

Adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to your CSS will fix that.

Comment: Then why are the cards above being displayed just fine ?

Comment: @MJ9094 Because they have whitespace

Comment: Look at the data of the last card, the word doesnt't contain any space so it wouldn't wrap.

Comment: It did work though. Thank you very much. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to React, it's css, if the words are seperated they will go to the new line, but if it's a long word, you'll need to use [word-wrap: break-word;](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

```css
#test {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* comment this line to see the difference */
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  asdlashsakjfhksdjhfksdhfgsdhfkghasdklfhaslfuqweopruf
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with post request breaking the UI. It's just that the word being used is very long and is respected by browser rendering engine. You should either formulate the review content correctly using spaces (not using impractical long words) or you can use css styling for break-word which is actually not recommended. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the string of text has no spaces between characters and it's been interpreted as a whole word. Try to pass a more formated text or if not you can use the CSS property `word-wrap: break-word;` as suggested above.